# pod repo push: -Swift.h file not found

Tags: swift, cocoapods

My `Objective-C` project`pod install`a `SwiftObject`, the usage is like this: `#import <SwiftObject / SwiftObject-Swift.h>` When my project `pod repo push`, I get an error: **`Headers / Public / OCObject / Family.h: 10: 9: Error: 'SwiftObject / SwiftObject-Swift.h' file not found '`**
My `podspec` file added something like:`spec.prefix_header_contents = '# import <SwiftObject / SwiftObject-Swift.h>'`, but it doesn't seem to work
How do I find the file?